# What should be passed in the '$dom' in the function domain_start($dom) below?

Tags: php, html

I am just little confused that what i should pass in the given below function so that it could start a virtual machine.

```
function domain_start($dom) {
        $dom=$this->get_domain_object($dom);
        if ($dom) {
            $ret = libvirt_domain_create($dom);
            $this->last_error = libvirt_get_last_error();
            return $ret;

        }
        $ret = libvirt_domain_create_xml($this->conn, $dom);
        $this->last_error = libvirt_get_last_error();
        return $ret;
}
```

Please correct me if i am doing something wrong.

Comment: Might make sense to mention and look into the default functions  https://libvirt.org/php/api-reference.html; some more context of whatever wrapper class you have might also be relevant. (Else this question is just "guess the code and usage".)

Comment: Yes, I am using functions  of libvirt-php. But what parameter should be passed to start a vm. As i have already tried with the uri, uuid, conn, name of the vm.

Comment: To start a vm, what should i do in my code.